# Incoming constraints for Container in Flutter. Do i get it wrong?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

As [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) says

> Containers with no children try to be as big as possible unless the
> incoming constraints are unbounded, in which case they try to be as
> small as possible

Well when I make incoming constraints unbounded for inner Container i suppose that it should be `as small as possible` but it expands for entire screen.

```dart
  body: Container(
    color: Colors.red,
    constraints: const BoxConstraints(
      maxHeight: double.infinity,
      maxWidth: double.infinity,
    ),
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
  ),
```

Why?[image]

Comment: your **Green** container doesnt have any child, then its expand as big as possible. 
try another widget, something like `Text` , `Icon` , etc . then the size will follow the child size

Comment: But documentation says `Containers with no children` )))

Comment: `Container( color: Colors.green,),`  this doesnt have any children

Comment: The point is not in the child's absense. Here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73413228/2618498

Comment: thats the point, the child is absense in your green container, thats why it push to the maximum size.
different result if the child not container, the red container will not take maximum size.

Comment: you may try  Container(
    color: Colors.red,
    constraints: const BoxConstraints(
      maxHeight: double.infinity,
      maxWidth: double.infinity,
    ),
    child: Text('lorem'),   

this will not take maximum size

Comment: Child is unnecessary, below András Szepesházi shows how we can force Container to be smallest size with `UnconstrainedBox` as its parent.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the documentation a bit further, you'll see that constraint arguments on the `Container` itself will override this behavior:

> Containers with no children try to be as big as possible unless the incoming constraints are unbounded, in which case they try to be as small as possible. Containers with children size themselves to their children. The width, height, and constraints arguments to the constructor override this.

Try wrapping the inner childless `Container` in an `UnconstrainedBox`, and you'll see it will shrink to zero width and height.

```
body: 
   Container(
    color: Colors.red,
    width: double.infinity,
    height:double.infinity,
    child: UnconstrainedBox(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
      ),
    ),
)
```

Comment: Really intricately )))

Comment: But if i try to override constraints directly in the CTR `(constraints: BoxConstraints.tight(          Size(0,0)))` instead of `UnconstraindeBox` above , as in documentation "and constraints arguments to the constructor override this." - I have no such effect.

Answer (score 2):

Although red container has infinite size, You put it in a scaffold's body which has specific size. so your red container get specific size then your green container with no child get size as much as its parents.

Comment: But accordingly "and constraints arguments to the constructor override this." red Container should override its parent's constraints, nope? And should pass its new constraints to green one as its nearest parent.

Comment: No it can override its parents, by setting double.infinity you tell the red container get size as much as your parent gives you.

Answer (score 0):

The red `container` actually will has size as small as posibble depends its child.

the green container has no child, then as the documentation said it will try to be as big as possible unless the incoming constraints are unbounded,

if you change the child , like Text widget, or Column, or other widget, it will not get the maximum size.